# How to get numeric value from excel file cell, using POI

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am pretty new to Selenium and learning through self study. Any help will be appreciable.

Currently I am using

`String data = wb.getSheetAt(sheetnum).getRow(row).getCell(col).getStringCellValue();`

It is working fine for String but not for numeric. I have a cell value of `'500'` and I want to fetch it. Please help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27688250/how-to-read-numeric-values-from-excel-in-java

Comment: @Debanjan There is a method defined as follows:  public String getData(int sheetnum, int row, int col)
 { 
 String data=wb.getSheetAt(sheetnum).getRow(row).getCell(col).getStringCellValue();
 return data;
 }                                                                                                                    The numeric field I want to choose is driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='Weight']")).sendKeys(excel.getData(1, 1, 9));

Comment: Please let me know of you need any more details.

Comment: @PaulamiSanyal Can you consider to put your code block & the entire error stacktrace in the question area for further analysis please? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try out following code :

```
public void readfile(String filepath, String filename, String sheetname)    throws IOException {


    File file = new File(filepath+"\\"+filename);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);

    // for creating .xlsx workbook
    Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);

    // for reading the sheet by its name
    Sheet sh = wb.getSheet(sheetname);

    // find the total rows in sheet

    int rowcount = sh.getLastRowNum() - sh.getFirstRowNum();

    // create a loop to create

    for (int i = 0; i < rowcount + 1; i++) {
        Row row = sh.getRow(i);

        // create a loop to print cell values

        for (int j = 0; j < row.getLastCellNum(); j++) {
            Cell cell = row.getCell(j);
            switch (cell.getCellType()) {
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                System.out.print(row.getCell(j).getStringCellValue() + " ");
                break;

            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                System.out.print((int)row.getCell(j).getNumericCellValue() + " ");
                break;

            }

        }

        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks @Debanjan and @RNS! Somehow I managed to do it  with below code.

Comment: Thanks @RNS. Somehow I managed to do it using below code and it worked.                                                                                             public String getNumericData(int sheetnum,int row, int col)
 {
 String data=String.valueOf((int)wb.getSheetAt(sheetnum).getRow(row).getCell(col).getNumericCellValue());
 return data;
 }

Answer (score 0):

```
Double data = wb.getSheetAt(sheetnum).getRow(row).getCell(col).getNumericCellValue();
```